# Selecting dataframe based on name in for loop - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a novice user of Python 3.8.5
How do i select a dataframe based on its name?
I have a string variable which matches to dataframe name, how do i map it to that particular dataframe for some math operation on it.

```
    dfsteps = ['0','1','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100']
for steps in dfsteps:
    dfa = 'df1_' + steps
    dfb = 'df2_' + steps
    dfc = 'df3_' + steps
     
    A1=dfa['Values1']
    A2=dfb['Values2']
    A3=dfc['Values3']
    
    A1max = A1.max()
    A2max = A2.max()
    A3max = A3.max()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `locals().get()` to get dataframe by string variable.

Example:

`locals().get(dfa)['Value1'].max()`

Comment: Great! It works just perfect for me and reduces my code size :) :) Thanks a Ton Atomyy!!